# How to test current input selectionRange/cursorPosition in the Protractor.js?

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor, e2e-testing

I just learn how to create `angular.js` directives.
I write simple directive for input with two-way binded `selectionRange` control.
When scope variable changes - selection range inside the input changes too.

How this behavior can be tested with `Protractor.js`?
I can not to find any method to get input current `selectionRange`/`cursor position` or even selected text.

---

You can found&playWith my directive here: [Demo](https://vparth.github.io/ng-tools/)
`Todo` with what I want to achive here: [github](https://github.com/vpArth/ng-tools/blob/master/e2e-tests/arthCursor.js#L86)

When you change $scope data with form below, input selection changes.
I want just cover this behavior with test, and don't know how to get current `selectionRange` in the protractor environment.

Comment: Could you please make a reproducible example (may be a plunker)? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, can you show me any ready plunkr with `protractor` environment? I just can't imagine how to write it..

Comment: Nono, the demo you've provided is what I've asked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483800/getting-currently-selected-text) I've recently solved with the help of @trincot:

```
expect(browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].value.substring(arguments[0].selectionStart, arguments[0].selectionEnd);", elm.getWebElement())).toEqual("selected part of the input text");
```

Here `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are used to get the currently selected text in an input.

Comment: Explain please about `getWebElement`. It returns usual `HTMLElement`?

Comment: @vp_arth `elm` in this case is an `ElementFinder` instance - what is returned by `element()` call. `getWebElement()` now is required to be called if we are passing an element to the script - it basically returns a regular `HTMLElement` out of a `ElementFinder`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @vp_arth I've also made an [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2290) so that there would be no need to explicitly call `getWebElement()` when passing an element into `executeScript()` as an argument. The issue is still open though.

Comment: protractor test-cases reading - it can be more useful than docs :)