# How to detect whether a specific range from string is in the newline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "this is test1
           this is test2
           this is test3";
```

Now I want if both sides of that range are `\n` then returns `true`, else return `false`. In the above example just these three ranges are true:

`[0 - 12]` =>  `true`

`[14 - 26]` => `true`

`[27 - 39]` => `true`

And all other ranges have to be `false`. Like these: `[1 - 12]`, `[5 - 17]`, ...

---

**Note:** Spaces before and after that range doesn't matter. For example:

```
var str = "     this is a test    ";
```

Now this ranges are `true`: `[0 - 20]`, `[2 - 18]`, `[5 - 22]`, ...

---

In reality, I'm trying to create a markdown-editor and now I'm working on its code-method button. So I need to know, if all of selected text (that range) is in a line, then append 4spaces before it, else append two "`" surround it.

Comment: Why wouldnt you just split the text on new lines and do what you need with the resultant array?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I don't get it... But  there is two cases ... appending four spaces before selected text (if all of that be on a line) or appending two colon surround it .. (if selected text is in the middle of line)

Comment: How is "range" determined ?

Comment: @guest271314 I have that range. I just need to detect all of that range is in a line or not ..

Comment: Tried using `$` _"Matches end of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately before a line break character."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries ?

Comment: If requirement is to determine if last character of selected text  is end of line , could use `$` at `RegExp` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes requirement is what you said plus if there is some spaces between the last character of selected text and end of line then still is should be `true`

Comment: Why use a regex at all? Search for the newline character with normal string functions, e.g. at position `15` and check if this is in the range `0-14` (no, it isn't).

Comment: @guest271314 btw, I need to check both sides of selected text *(that range)*, not just the end of that.

Comment: @Jan Do you mean I check all before and after character until a `\n` using a `loop` and `if`?

Comment: @stack See post. Try selecting all contents of `textarea` element at stacksnippets, results at `console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `onselect` event , storing each line of input text within an array, checking each line for saved variable using `RegExp` `\n` . See also [Getting currently selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483800/getting-currently-selected-text)

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea"), re = /\n/;

textarea.onselect = function(e) {
  var res = [];
  // current selection
  var sel = this.value.slice(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd);
  // create array of input value split at new line characters
  var matches = this.value.split(re);
  // split input value at new line characters
  // return `true` or `false`
  var selected = sel.split(re);
  for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    if (matches.indexOf(selected[i]) !== -1) {
      res.push(true)
    } else {
      res.push(false)
    }
  }

  console.log(matches, res, selected)
}
```

```html
<textarea style="width:300px;height:200px">
  this is test1
  this is test2
  this is test3</textarea>
```

Comment: It returns `true` just for last line of textarea .. Am I write?

Comment: @stack _"It returns true just for last line of textarea .. Am I write? "_ Yes. Is this expected result ?

Comment: I want if all of selected text is in a line then return `true`. So, in your example, it should returns `true` for three cases: 1. if all of first line is selected, 2. if all of second line is selected, 3. is all of third line is selected

Comment: @stack Same process. Reference entire `textarea` `value` , compare if selected text matches each line of `textarea` value

Comment: It returns `true` just for first line, and also it returns `[true, true, true]` if I select all three lines together .. otherwise returns `false`

Comment: See updated post. Note, matches spaces within line as part of selection. Could use `.trim()` on variables to remove this portion of check

Comment: Well, Now seems perfect ... Thanks +1

Comment: Just one thing, your code returns a separated `true` or `false` for each line. May you please tell me how can I implement it which returns just one `true` or `false` in total?

Comment: Try using `.some()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some or `.every()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Look, every thing is fine ... Just the spaces surround selected text acts like characters .. I want when you select `this is test1` *(without the spaces around it)* from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jmwe433g/1/),  it returns `true`, but it returns `false`, because there is some spaces surround selected text. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Very good, thanks pal. That fiddle is exactly what  I needed.

Comment: Oh ... A really odd thing: Please open [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmwe433g/11/) and select second `sa` in the second line. It returns `true` ... Why? Do you know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101810/discussion-between-guest271314-and-stack).